# Python Google authentication for a program used for web scraping

Tags: python, authentication

Never done this but, I'm trying to build a program, that would scrape a google classroom site specific to the user that's logged in. Even when logged in the main browser google denies the request and instead gives me authentication error (I need to login in other words) how can I be logged in, in the program so that google accepts my request and grants me to scrape classroom sites.

Tried this solution but without luck: [Logging into Google using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754709/logging-in-to-google-using-python)

It was published a while ago and google could have changed the requirements for these kind of program authentication.

What I desire is to get into the section only available for me when I'm logged in, e.g. content of my classroom and grab some text from it, is it even possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would be expensive to try and implement a log-in mechanism, especially with all the 2FA requirements of Google solutions today.

What would be quicker and usually works in software automation today is to have a manually logged in session and then start the browser with the user data directory pointed to it. This is how it's usually achieved and the relogin is done manually from time to time, only when needed. More info on how to set up a user data directory [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#Overriding-the-User-Data-Directory).

This gets you up and running pretty fast.